# Ordering of Turing machines?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

I am new to Turing Machines. As in I’ve been reading about them over the last two days. So I am not very knowledgeable at this moment.

I was also reading about the Kleene’s O system of ordinal notations, in its definition, there is a statement that involves lexicographically ordering Turing Machines. My question is:

> How are they ordered?

Thanks

Comment: Lexicographically. I don't know this exact implementation, but it sounds to me like you just order them like you would order words in a dictionary: Order them by the first letter in some arbitrary way, then among those with the same first letter, order them by the second letter, and so on. In this case, by the first defining component, then the second, and so on. Look at your definition of Turing machines, and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Letters on the tape, the input language or the tape language? That doesn’t really make too much sense to me, but I kind of get what your pointing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said, which order you use doesn't matter, just the fact that there is one.  First you have to clearly define your notation for a Turing machine.

One approach I have seen is as follows:
A state of a Turning machine is defined as a tuple $(n,w0,m0,s0,w1,m1,s1)$  where
$n$ is the state number
$w0$ is the character written to the tape if there was a $0$ present
$m0$ is the direction to move the tape one space if there was a $0$ present
$s0$ is the state to go to if there was a $0$ present
and similarly for the items with a $1$ for when there was a $1$ present.  By convention we always start at state $0$.

A Turing machine is a tuple of states where the state numbers are in sequential order starting from $0$.

Now there is an obvious lexicographic order.  The first character is always $0$ because we have required that.  We put all the machines where state $0$ has $w0=0$ before those with $w0=1$.  Within each of those groups we put the ones with $m0=L$ before those with $m0=R$.  We then break ties the value of $s0$ and so on.

Usually in this area we don't order functions, we order machines.  There are lots of machines that add two numbers.  Once you have one that works, you can add more states at the end without changing anything because the new states are never used.  These machines each come somewhere in the order, but we have no way to pick out all the equivalent "adding machines".

Answer (score 1):

Turing machines can be described by a list of parameters, like list of states, list of transitions, etc. This is a finite string, so every Turing machine can be identified with a finite string. Now order these strings lexicographically.

Comment: But which order do we put the parameters in?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, a fixed one. You should have some ordering given in the lecture or book you are learning from. I haven't encountered a problem yet where the order actually mattered; only the fact that there exists one and we can enumerate all machines was ever important (again, at least in the cases I saw when studying Turing machines).

Comment: I’m a high school student with an interest in logic and set theory. I can’t afford textbooks, and I don’t attend lectures, so I learn from random information scattered across the internet, and I have been doing so for the last 5 years.

Comment: Also, how do you order states? And functions, other than by symbols that represent them?

Comment: The ordering of states is indeed an interesting question. I think there was a way to define an order on them, but I can't fully remember now. For your learning, I would suggest to find lecture notes/youtube videos/... that completely discuss a certain topic. Between different authors and sources, notations and some concept might be different, so taking random information from everywhere is not always efficient.

Comment: Yeah, it’s probably not. Thanks. I’ll try and figure that out...

Comment: @L.McDonald: It can be *very* dangerous to learn random information scattered on the internet. It's easy to find things which are out of context, which are out of your element, and which are confusing without a careful guiding hand. It's not hard to find free books on the internet. You can say that you're not *really* committed to this, and it's fine, no one will hold it against you. But this is not how you *should* learn *anything*.